# Lua cannot open libcairo with error "undefined symbol: luaopen_libcairo"

Tags: module, lua, cairo, conky

I am trying to configure conky to work with cairo, I added "require 'libcairo'" to the top of the default .conkyrc to make sure it would load, however, when I run conky, it gives me this error:

```
error loading module 'libcairo' from file './libcairo.so':
./libcairo.so: undefined symbol: luaopen_libcairo
```

I have been browsing other related questions, and most suggest that the lua version and cairo library are mismatched. I have ensured that i am using Lua 5.3 and i compiled the latest version of Cairo from the tarball on their downloads page (version 1.17.4).

I tried using the Lua interpreter to load the module and determine what was actually causing the error, however when i give it

```
>require 'libcairo'
```

it returns the same error.

After purging and reinstalling conky, lua, and libcairo, it still is not working. I do not know where I am going wrong but I would be happy to provide any info the reader will need to help.

EDIT: I should add that I am using Arch with KDE5

Comment: What Lua binding for Cairo have you built?

Comment: You need to use `require 'cairo'`, not libcairo.

Comment: @meuh, the only libraries that were installed 'libcairo'. a serch on my machine turned up no libraries by the name 'cairo'.

Comment: @AlexanderMashin  forgive me if i sound ignorant, but i do not know what a Lua binding is. I have 0 experience with Lua.

Comment: I understood that "lib" will be added automatically to the require argument. All the conky examples seem to use `require 'cairo'`, not  `require 'libcairo'`.

Comment: If `require 'cairo'` fails, try `require 'Cairo'`.

Comment: When you built conky from source, did you enable the `BUILD_LUA_CAIRO` flag?  https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/wiki/Installation#build_flags  You'd also need the dev-headers for that `sudo apt install libcairo2-dev`

Comment: @AlexanderMashin, capitalizing Cairo also did help, but here in the comments I see that i likely made two errors:

I didn't build conky with proper flags,
i didn't install dev headers for libcairo2

I will try both of these things and report back here once I've finished

Comment: @Doyousketch2 Sorry, i didn't clarify, I did not compile Conky from source, i used pacman to install it. I however will try building it from source to see if that clears the issue. Please indulge me on how to enable specific build flags? i checked the README and some other places but it only shows me how to list them. I'll play around with it till i figure it out, but if you get to this before that I'd like to know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install libcairo2-dev
```

You've probably done these following commands, but the difference is in the cmake.
Just include `-D` then the name of the flag you wish to use.

```
mkdir build  
cd build  
cmake -DBUILD_LUA_CAIRO=true ..  
nice make -j$(nproc)  
sudo make install
```

https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/blob/master/cmake/ConkyBuildOptions.cmake

---

Cairo *possibly* needs Pango.  I won't say you have to install it, but if the above command doesn't get you where you're going, then I'd look at pango / freetype libs as a possible source as to why.

```
sudo apt install libpango1.0-dev
cmake -DBUILD_LUA_CAIRO=true -DBUILD_XFT=true ..
```

Comment: Obviously substitute `pacman` commands in where needed, I'm used to Debian.

Answer (score 0):

On Pop!_OS 21.04 (= Ubuntu 20.04 plus some extras) I simply had to install the conky-all package, it uninstalls conky-std which does not work with Cairo.